# Converting array into an Object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

I have an array which contains multiple objects:

```
  var getUsers = function (){
    allUsers = [];

    $().SPServices({
      operation: "GetUserCollectionFromSite",
      completefunc: function(xData, Status){
        var responseXML = $(xData.responseXML);
        responseXML.find("User").each(function(){
          allUsers.push({
            id: $(this).attr("ID"),
            name: $(this).attr("Name"),
            domain: $(this).attr("LoginName"),
            email: $(this).attr("Email"),
            isAdmin: $(this).attr("IsSiteAdmin")
          });
        });
      }
    });
    return allUsers;
  }
```

I'm trying to change it so that instead of using an array, `allUsers` is an object instead and the top level property is the ID and each ID property contains user information.

This is what I tried but it kinda cause my application to stall for some reason.

```
var getUsers = function (){
      allUsers = {};

    $().SPServices({
      operation: "GetUserCollectionFromSite",
      completefunc: function(xData, Status){
        var responseXML = $(xData.responseXML);
        responseXML.find("User").each(function(){
            //This is pretty much where I'm at a lost
          allUsers[$(this).attr("ID")]:{
            name: $(this).attr("Name"),
            domain: $(this).attr("LoginName"),
            email: $(this).attr("Email"),
            isAdmin: $(this).attr("IsSiteAdmin")
          };
        });
      }
    });
    return allUsers;
  }
```

I'm trying to get an object that is structured like this:

```
var allUsers = {
    "68": {
        id: 68,
        name: 'mike',
        domain: 'i: 0#.f | admembers | mike.ca',
        email: 'mike.ca',
        isAdmin: false
    }
};
```

PS: sorry for the bad title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo here:

```
allUsers[$(this).attr("ID")] : {
                             ^
```

`:` should be `=` as this is an assignment to a key.

```
allUsers[$(this).attr("ID")] = {
```

Everything else looks fine. Except you could assign `$(this)` to a variable to save you making DOM lookups.

```
var self = $(this);
```

Comment: Works, thanks. I tried setting the var self outside the function, within my service but for some reason that didn't work. Other than that, seems to work fine.

Comment: Yea that's what I noticed. I was purposefully trying not to put it in there so that it wouldn't have to declare it so often but I guess it won't work otherwise.

Comment: @Batman It's because the `this` needs to refer to the element that is being iterated over, which is the scope of that function.

Answer (score 1):

Just replace `:` with `=`, in line `allUsers[$(this).attr("ID")] : {`

```
  allUsers[$(this).attr("ID")] = {
    id: $(this).attr("ID"),
    name: $(this).attr("Name"),
    domain: $(this).attr("LoginName"),
    email: $(this).attr("Email"),
    isAdmin: $(this).attr("IsSiteAdmin")
  };
```

Comment: `this.id` instead of `$(this).attr('ID')` _may_ be better?

Comment: @qwertnl would it know that it's looking for the id attribute from the current xml node?